# When will the ADT plugin work with Eclipse 8.0?

Tags: windows-7

The ADT plugin requires Eclipse 3.0 or 3.5.

I would like to upgrade my PC from Vista to Windows 7. But Eclipse 3.5 is not compatible with Windows 7 (as of today, 5/3/2010).  Eclipse 8.0 is compatible with Windows 7, but the ADT plugin requires versions 3.0 or 3.5.  Any solution in sight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running eclipse classic 3.5.2 (32bit) on Windows 7 (64bit) no problem.

I'm not even sure where you get Eclipse 8 from. As far as I know 3.5 is the most current version.